# PHP: how to switch from raw SQL query to laravel raw query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

When switching to Laravel, SQL queries are changed.

From this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

to:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

(I want to use SQL raw queries in LARAVEL to make rewriting the code easier https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries)

Sorry if this question is obvious, but I'm a beginner and don't understand the other answers I've found. Now what to add to the new code, so the old $result and new $result behave the same?

Because new $result is an array, right? I need to have the new $result behave like the old $result  to change the code easily.

Optional: do you know which topics I need to learn to understand this better myself?

Comment: Do you think sql row is essier than laravel eloquent query ??

Comment: right now it doesnt seem easier because im not familiar with it. Will laravel eloqent query accept things like hex() lower() substr() rpad() now() timestampdiff() ?

Comment: `DB::select("your_raw_sql_query");`. So it also simple as like